# how to disable php file direct access based on url, for particular subfolders only

Tags: php, .htaccess

Problem with htaccess files permission.

I have few files with .php extension in root folder which can be accessed in website as `example.com/myprofile.php`

I have another file(myprofileservice.php) in directory(service) as: `example.com/service/myprofileservice.php`

This myprofileservice.php will provide necessary information from backend when `url: example.com/myprofile.php` is accessed in browser.

I want to disable viewing php files but only for directory "service" not the root.

Preventing .php file access  by rule

```
RewriteRule .*\.(php)$ - [F,NC]
```

prevents the `example.com/myprofile.php` itself to load , which is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^service/myprofileservice.php$ - [F,L]
```

This will forbid access to a single php file **service/myprofileservice.php** .

Comment: ok, so in case i want to forbid many such backend php files, will i have to write as many rows in htaccess?

Comment: You dont need to write multiple lines, you can regex based pattern to handle requests, to block all php files inside /service folder ,try this patter **^service/.+\.php$**